# Ant Design - Form Item Custom rule triggering only when the input is different than the original value

Tags: forms, antd, rules

I have a Ant Design Form Item with a custom rule to check for name uniqueness.  I only want this to be triggered in the edit scenario if the name was changed.

For example, the user edits an existing object named "Bob", he changes the name to "Fred".
In this scenario I want the validation to be triggered.

If the user edits the existing object called "Fred", and doesnt edit this field, but edits another field on the form I don't want the name uniqueness to be triggered.

```
 <Form.Item
        name="name"
        label="name"
      
        rules={[
          {
            required: true,
            message: "Please input the name",
            }),
          },
          () => {
            return {
              validator: uniqueNameValidator,
            };
          },
        ]}
      >
        <Input autoFocus data-cy="dir-create-name" />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item
        name="desc"
        label="Description",
        })}
      >
        <Input.TextArea data-cy="dir-create-desc" />
      </Form.Item>
```

I am not sure if there is a way to compare values, and only do the validation if the previous value doesn't match the new value